# Why cannot use lambda to define prototype function

Tags: javascript, lambda

Can someone please explain why defining a prototype function with lambda expression doesn't work? I thought this must be asked before but couldn't find it.

```
function Book(title, year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;

    // define a function within the object, which works fine
    this.printYear = () => console.log("instance function of an object: " + this.year);
}
```

this doesn't work

```
Book.prototype.printTitle2 = () => {
        console.log(this.title);
    }
```

and this is fine of course:

```
Book.prototype.printTitle = function() {
         console.log(this);
         console.log(this.title);
    }
```

Comment: fat arrows don't have `this`

Comment: @georg I think it does but just not what I thought it was.

Comment: @stt106: georg's comment is correct other than that it's missing two words: "a" and "binding": "arrows don't have a `this` binding". A "binding" is the mechanism the JavaScript spec uses to talk about resolving things like `this`, variable names, and constant names. For instance, a function declaring a variable called "a" has a *binding* for that variable (indirectly through an env record). Normal functions have a *binding* for `this` which is set to a value when they're called, but arrow functions don't, which is why they close over the `this` binding of the context in which they're created.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the chief features of arrow functions is that they *close over* the `this` from the context in which they're created; they don't get it based on how they're called like other functions do. So...

```
// ...whatever `this` is *here*
Book.prototype.printTitle2 = () => {
    // ...is what `this` will be *here*
    console.log(this.title);
};
```

But your function relies on `this` varying depending on how it's called.

This just isn't a use-case for arrow functions. Use a normal function:

```
Book.prototype.printTitle2 = function() {
    console.log(this.title);
};
```

Or better yet, use the new `class` syntax:

```
class Book {
    constructor(title, year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
    }

   printTitle2() {
        console.log(this.title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The `Arrow function` would resolve the context `this` belongs to the scope where the function was defined. I believe you have defined that function in `window` scope. So the `this` will point to `window` in your function.

You can use normal `anonymous function` here. And we have to be careful while using arrow functions.

Comment: thanks and that makes sense now; but I am going to accept the other answer as it provides a bit more insight; hope you wouldn't mind.

Comment: @stt106 You are free to do that. Glad to help by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@t-j-crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234410/3793309), I wanted to leave a test case (mocha assert) which you can use to visualize which is not working.

Also you can read more about the scope of arrow functions here:
[You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#not-just-shorter-syntax-but-this)
by Kyle Simpson, who explains `this` in detail.

Basically, an arrow function's `this` points to the surrounding context of the current context, which comes in handy if you have enclosing functions.
What it does is basically doing the `var self = this;` thing.

Or as Kyle says:

> [...]
>   Lexical `this` in the arrow function callback in the previous snippet now points to the same value as in the enclosing `makeRequest(..)` function. In other words, `=>` is a syntactic stand-in for `var self = this`.
>
> In cases where `var self = this` (or, alternatively, a function `.bind(this)` call) would normally be helpful, `=>` arrow functions are a nicer alternative operating on the same principle. [...]

You can test it yourself with my gist:
https://gist.github.com/jay-bricksoft/96738dd8a48ceb9f517e914b834cc1ee

In my test case this was the output:

```
Lambda
    function(){}
      √ should equal function´s type
      1) should have equal context as function
      2) should be able to be used as constructor
  1 passing (39ms)
  2 failing
  1) Lambda function(){} should have equal context as function:
      AssertionError: 'undefined' == 'string'
      + expected - actual
      -undefined
      +string

      at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.js:29:14)
  2) Lambda function(){} should be able to be used as constructor:
     TypeError: construct_l is not a constructor
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.js:34:20)
```

EDIT: added example / reference to Kyle Simpson's "You Don't Know ES6"
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20%26%20beyond