# Why can't we create prototypes using ES6 Arrow Functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

First, I create a ES5 Function and then create it's prototype:

```js
var Person = function() {};

Person.prototype.city = function() {return 'New York'}
```

I get no error in here. But when I create the same with ES6 fat arrow function, I get `Cannot set property 'city' of undefined`:

```js
let Person = () => {};

Person.prototype.city = () => {return 'New York'}
```

Why is this?

Comment: "Arrow functions do not have a prototype property" --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why cannot use lambda to define prototype function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234359/why-cannot-use-lambda-to-define-prototype-function)

Comment: Even you could do this, arrow functions are not *constructable*, i.e. they cannot be called with `new`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Comment: @MarkMeyer No, this is not a duplicate of that question. This one is about attempting to use a prototype on an arrow function and the other is about assigning an arrow function to another function's prototype.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because by definition, arrow functions don't have prototypes. They're designed to be lightweight, without some of the baggage that old-style functions have.

Another likely reason for this is that arrow functions capture the surrounding `this` rather than having it determined dynamically. So they would serve poorly as constructor functions because the `this` within them would be referring to the `this` from the surrounding scope instead of the object being created. (In fact, you can't even use them as constructor functions. JavaScript will throw an error if you try to.)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> ## Use of prototype property
>
> Arrow functions do not have a prototype property.
>
> ```
> var Foo = () => {};
> console.log(Foo.prototype); // undefined
> ```

Comment: Why so? I mean how these arrow function work actually in the constructor?

Comment: @Sanjay Just edited my answer. You shouldn't use an arrow function as a constructor. If you need a constructor, use a regular function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Gotcha!

Comment: @JLRishe: *"You shouldn't use an arrow function as a constructor."* It's not even possible. Calling an arrow function with `new` throws an error.