# How to fix 'Not a constructor function' error in javascirpt

Tags: javascript-objects

I'm trying to understand how object prototypes work and hence tried out a piece of code from 'Javascript: The Good Parts' book and got an error.

I modified the code just for fun and got the error. It works and shows an output if the original code is ran.

This is the **original code** and it gave no errors.

```js
let stooge = {
    'first-name': 'John',
    'last-name' : 'Peter'
};

if(typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
Object.create = (o) => {
    let F = () => {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};
}

let theOtherStooge = Object.create(stooge);
console.log(theOtherStooge['first-name'], theOtherStooge['last-name']);
```

I removed the if condition and got an error saying F isn't a constructor function. Could someone explain me why this is happening? Please excuse me, I'm a beginner to programming.

**Modified code:**

```js
let stooge = {
    'first-name': 'John',
    'last-name' : 'Peter'
};

Object.create = (o) => {
let F = () => {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};

let theOtherStooge = Object.create(stooge);
console.log(theOtherStooge['first-name'], theOtherStooge['last-name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in Chrome `Object.create` is already defined as a function, so none of the code in the `if` statement of the first example is being run.  Without the `if` statement, the code throwing the exception is run.  The reason for the error is that the lambda function assigned to `F` is not considered a constructor.  Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234410/2554810), the problem is that the `this` object is assigned to the scope surrounding a lambda function when it is *created*, while `this` is assigned to the object *calling* the function when using a regular function.  You can change the code to use a regular function instead:

```js
let stooge = {
  'first-name': 'John',
  'last-name': 'Peter'
};

Object.create = (o) => {
  let F = function() {};
  F.prototype = o;
  return new F();
};

let theOtherStooge = Object.create(stooge);
console.log(theOtherStooge['first-name'], theOtherStooge['last-name']);
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, arrow functions cannot be used as constructors.